# Python3 and Setuptools: Problem with running a script after installing an EGG file (ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: python, setuptools

I am having some trouble trying to run a script after building an EGG file for my pkgs using Python3/setuptools. I am able to run the script OK if I use **zip_safe=False** in *setup.py*. But I get a *ModuleNotFoundError* otherwise. What am I doing wrong? I would prefer not to use **zip_safe=False** option.

My project is structured as follows:

```
.
|-- python_pkgs
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- acap
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- acap.py
|   |   |-- cfg
|   |   |-- pch_acap.pl
|   |   |-- spf.py
|   |   `-- tvpv.py
|   |-- parsers
|   |   |-- STIL1999ModelBuilderSemantics.py
|   |   |-- STIL1999Parser.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- grammars
|   |   `-- test
|   `-- utils
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- misc.py
|       |-- nbq.py
|       |-- splitter.py
|       `-- util.py
|-- run_acap.py
`-- setup.py
```

The contents of run_acap.py:

```
    #!/nfs/sc/disks/mpe_tvpv_032/sw_tools/anaconda3/bin/python3.7 -B
    import sys
    print(sys.path)

    from python_pkgs.acap.acap import main

    if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
```

The contents of setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages

setup(
    name='python_pkgs',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_namespace_packages(include=['python_pkgs.*'],
                                     exclude=['python_pkgs.parsers',
                                              'python_pkgs.parsers.*']),
    scripts=['run_acap.py']
)
```

To install I say: python setup.py install --prefix **a path**

The install directory contents look like this:

```
$ tree
.
|-- bin
|   `-- run_acap.py
`-- lib
    `-- python3.7
        `-- site-packages
            |-- easy-install.pth
            |-- python_pkgs-0.1-py3.7.egg
            `-- site.py
```

I notice the contents of bin/run_acap.py is a bit different:

```
#!/nfs/sc/disks/mpe_tvpv_032/sw_tools/anaconda3/bin/python -B
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'python-pkgs==0.1','run_acap.py'
__requires__ = 'python-pkgs==0.1'
__import__('pkg_resources').run_script('python-pkgs==0.1', 'run_acap.py')
```

Now to run this script, I say:

```
setenv PYTHONPATH <a path>/lib/python3.7/site-packages
<a path>/bin/run_acap.py --help



 $ /nfs/sc/disks/mpe_tvpv_032/pgupta6/releases/acap/ww49.2/bin/run_acap.py --help
['/nfs/sc/disks/mpe_tvpv_032/pgupta6/releases/acap/ww49.2/bin', '/nfs/sc/disks/mpe_tvpv_032/pgupta6/releases/acap/ww49.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/nfs/sc/disks/mpe_tvpv_032/pgupta6/releases/acap/ww49.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/python_pkgs-0.1-py3.7.egg', '/nfs/sc/disks/mpe_tvpv_032/sw_tools/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/nfs/sc/disks/mpe_tvpv_032/sw_tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', '/nfs/sc/disks/mpe_tvpv_032/sw_tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/nfs/sc/disks/mpe_tvpv_032/sw_tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/nfs/sc/disks/mpe_tvpv_032/pgupta6/releases/acap/ww49.2/bin/run_acap.py", line 4, in <module>
        __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('python-pkgs==0.1', 'run_acap.py')
      File "/nfs/sc/disks/mpe_tvpv_032/sw_tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 666, in run_script
        self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
      File "/nfs/sc/disks/mpe_tvpv_032/sw_tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1469, in run_script
        exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
      File "/nfs/sc/disks/mpe_tvpv_032/pgupta6/releases/acap/ww49.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/python_pkgs-0.1-py3.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/run_acap.py", line 11, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_pkgs'
```

But if I open up a python interpreter and just type **import python_pkgs** the import works OK. I am not sure what I am doing wrong in my setup.py file (or somewhere else). How to fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: `setenv` is a `csh` command, perhaps if you are using a Bourne-compatible shell you should simply be doing `PYTHONPATH=<a path>/lib/python3.7/site-packages`?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am using tcsh shell. I don't think that is the issue as the 'setenv' command is issued in the xterm (i.e., it is not part of some script). The run_acap.py --help command is also issued in the xterm after PYTHONPATH env variable is defined.

Comment: To debug further, I added a *print(sys.path)* to run_acap.py to print the PYTHONPATH; post is updated to reflect this. The path looks OK to me.

Comment: Yeah, it should be okay; the nonstandard shell threw me off since you didn't mention it anywhere.